# xmllint: Remove <?xml version="1.0"?>

Tags: xmllint

I am using xmllint to clean up my .xml file but for some reason the output adds `<?xml version="1.0"?>` to the first line. Is there a flag to have this be removed?

Comment: I guess, you are aware, that that line is actually required for the XML file to be a valid XML file?

Comment: I know it is a strange request but the files I am dealing with do not have it but they are valid xml otherwise. I wanted to stay consistent and not have the xml version.

Comment: people should be a bit more conservative with their down-votes, this question is fine. +1

Comment: Use regex to remove it afterwards?

Comment: Pipe it through `tail -n +2` to remove the first line...

Comment: @Hristo-Iliev That line is not required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of the following seem to avoid insertion of `<?xml version="1.0"?>`:

- `xmllint --exc-c14n data.xml`
- `xmllint --c14n data.xml`

Hint:

`xmllint --help`

-or-

`man xmllint`